# Can the restored copy of an S3 Glacier object be deleted early?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When a `RestoreObject` call is used to restore an object from Glacier cold storage, it creates a temporary copy in S3 standard storage. Until the temporary copy expires, the file behaves as if it was in standard storage and you can download it. The temporary copy doesn't behave like a separate file, so for example, you can't delete it with `DeleteObject`.

Is there a way to delete the temporary copy before it expires, when it is no longer needed, to reduce standard storage costs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, after restoring an object, you can update the restore time.  From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_RestoreObject.html):

> After restoring an archived object, you can update the restoration period by reissuing the request with a new period. Amazon S3 updates the restoration period relative to the current time and charges only for the request-there are no data transfer charges. You cannot update the restoration period when Amazon S3 is actively processing your current restore request for the object.

So, once you're done with the object that has a long restore window, issue a new restore-object request for some small duration like 1 day, and it will return to cold storage sooner.